# Editing system menu using InsertMenuItem() not working correctly

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to add an "About" menu item in the second place of the system menu, but it's showing up last!

[image]

```
HMENU hSystemMenu = GetSystemMenu(hWnd, FALSE);

MENUITEMINFO mii_system;
mii_system.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
mii_system.fMask = MIIM_STRING | MIIM_ID;
mii_system.wID = 1005;
mii_system.dwTypeData = "About";

InsertMenuItem(hSystemMenu, 1, FALSE, &mii_system);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BOOL WINAPI InsertMenuItem(
  _In_  HMENU hMenu,
  _In_  UINT uItem,
  _In_  BOOL fByPosition,
  _In_  LPCMENUITEMINFO lpmii
);

fByPosition [in]
Type: BOOL
```

Controls the meaning of uItem. If this parameter is FALSE, uItem is a menu item identifier. Otherwise, it is a menu item position.

I'm guessing you want position 1, not item ID 1.  In that case, you would want this to be TRUE.

Comment: I forgot about that, I thought that FALSE means a menu item position. Thanks.